# Issue using RDP from Windows 7 to Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-7, remote-desktop, rdp

I'm trying to connect from my Windows 7 machine (home edition) to a Windows 2008 Server.  I am receiving an error stating "Your credentials did not work".  I have tested connecting over the Cord application from my Mac (to the same Server) and this works fine.

I have tried the following:

- Domain/Username combination
- Disabled Firewall completely on the Windows Server
- Allowed all remote sessions
- Tried to connect from different Window machines & versions

How can connecting via the Cord application work but connecting via Windows 7 doesn't?

Comment: What research or troubleshooting have you done so far?

Comment: domain/username combination, turn off firewall completely on Windows server, allowing remote desktop on allowed list of programs, trying to connect from different Windows machines and windows versions

Comment: Firstly, are you able to connect to this Windows Server via another Windows based machine (or connect to another server from this machine)? I know you have tried this but what was the outcome...

In addition to this, did you add the domain (or server name if you're using a local account) before the logon name? Example being: DOMAIN\USERNAME (ensure it's a backslash rather than forward (in the question you state you've used a forward slash))?

Lastly have you tried a different account (possibly a local account) to see if you receive the same issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem, it was password. Password has contained some special symbols so when I typed them over Cord they were identical how I typed but when I typed over windows remote desktop, some of symbols or multiple symbols were false. Now I changed password to password without special symbols and everything is ok. Thank you all for help.

Answer (score 3):

I have had a similar issue a while back. Ended up being that, although I was only putting in `login` in CoRD's dialog, it was actually sending the [down-level login name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380525(v=vs.85).aspx) (`domain\login`) to the server.

Once I added `domain\` prefix to `login` on RDP, it all worked.

Hope this helps.

Comment: tried that. Everything works's over Cord but over windows remote desktop connection does not.

Comment: Oh okay. Missed your comment. You may want to add it to the actual question. Trying to think of other possibilities. I'll update my answer if I do. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

> trying to connect from different Windows machines and windows versions

Can you confirm that ALL Windows machines consistently failed to login to your Win2k8 server via RDP?

Are they all in the same domain? If not, confirm you're not using the wrong domain/computer specification in the login field (e.g. "domain\user" or "computer\user").

Login to Win2k8, open the Event Viewer and check the Security events for errors.

Answer (score 0):

Just a shot in the dark here, but are you trying the hostname or the ip address when using using RDP?

Also does the network have a Domain Controller? And if so, are you using static IPs?

I've had many issues with RDP in the past simply because I'd not configured/updated the network adapter on my machine to account for the appropriate network and dns configurations.

For good measure, try replicating the appropriate network configs from the Mac to your 7 machine and see if RDP works at that point.

Answer (score 0):

If the error coming back is "invalid credentials", it is likely to be something about the way the login username string is being passed.

You already said you tried domain\username, but what about just the username forcing a blank domain (this is done putting a backward slash before the username like this: \myuser)?

Also, what do you see in the logs from the Windows Server?